# JQuery validate dynamically added input fields against other dynamically added input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, razor, unobtrusive-validation

I have multiple pairs of input fields for start and end dates:

```
@foreach (var exam in exams){
        <input type="date" data-val="true" required id="StartDate" value="exam.StartDate">
        <input type="date" data-val="true" data-val-endError="Can't be before start date" required>
}
```

I'm using jQuery's validator.AddMethod to validate that the end date is after the starting date:

```
$.validator.addMethod("endError",
function (value, element, params) {

    var startDate = $("#StartDate").on('input').val();

    if (value.toString() <= startDate) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("endError");
```

The problem is the validation is always comparing the end dates to the first starting date. I want each end date to be compared to it's relevant starting date.

I'm still a newbie in javascript but I know that this is probably caused by the id being the same for all the startDate inputs, which is illegal html.

Is there a way to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: `@`foreach.....its asp.net?

Comment: razor page in .net core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem with your code is you are referencing always the same id `StartDate`
so its normal the validation is always from the same startdate. When you have lot of same id the search of id stops always at the first.

```
@foreach (var exam in exams){
        <input type="date" data-val="true" required id="****StartDate*****" value="exam.StartDate">
        <input type="date" data-val="true" data-val-endError="Can't be before start date" required>
}
```

and you have the same id for different tag, its not good in html.

in your validator, you reference the StartDate id

```
var startDate = $("#StartDate").on('input').val();
```

one solution will be to create an id indexed :

```
@{int i=1;}
@foreach (var exam in exams){
        <input type="date" data-val="true" required id="StartDate@(i)" value="exam.StartDate">
        <input type="date" data-val="true" data-val-endError="Can't be before start date" required>

    i++;
}
```

you adapt the validator to trap the right id.

i suggest you to create an attribute `data-id` for example, and you put the id of StarDate: so in validator you trap the id of right date

```
$.validator.addMethod("endError", function (value, element, params) {
    var idstartDate = $(element).attr("data-id");
    var startDate= $(idstartDate).on('input').val();
      :
```

and you modify the loop:

```
@{int i=1;}
@foreach (var exam in exams){
        <input type="date" data-val="true" required id="StartDate@(i)" value="exam.StartDate">
        <input type="date" data-id="#StartDate@(i)" data-val="true" data-val-endError="Can't be before start date" required>

    i++;

}
```